# Python - My output is reversed in the CSV

Tags: python, regex, csv

This Program scans through files in a directory, and extracts data using REGEX (patterns).

The problem i am having is the output is like:

[image: CSV_OUTPUT]

Output from the program looks like:

[image: Print output from program]

It prints correctly but the CSV only takes one entry and is not correctly assigned to columns.
I would like to get it that the program will not do this

```
['EE-Data,DEC23,144009,TO,From,0000', 'FF-Data,DEC23,144009,TO,From,0000', 'GG-Data,DEC23,144009,TO,From,0000', 'HH-Data,DEC23,144009,TO,From,0000']
file2.TXT
['AA-Data,DEC23,144009,TO,From,0000', 'BB-DATA,DEC23,144509,TO,From,0000', 'CC-Data,DEC23,144009,TO,From,0000', 'DD-Data,DEC23,144009,TO,From,0000']
file1.TXT
```

BUT do this into the CSV

```
['AA-Data']['DEC23']['144009']['TO']['From']['0000']['File1.TXT']
['']['']['']['']['']['']['']
['']['']['']['']['']['']['']
['']['']['']['']['']['']['']
ETC
```

If I want to add more patterns they will go onto each row etc.

```
# use regex on a directory of files and copy into a CSV
import re
import glob
import csv
import os


#Pattern REGEX configuration
patternCPECCC1 = "\/CC(.*?)\/C1"
patternCPET5S6 = "\/T5(.*?)\/S6"


path = "/test/"

#CSV headers
header = ['Column1', 'Column2', 'Column3', 'Column4', 'Column5', 'Column6', 'Column7'] # add more as I expand out the Patterns

# to search DIR defined in path
for files in glob.glob(path +"*.TXT"):
    infile = open(files)
    fin = infile.read()
    pat1 = re.findall(patternCPECCC1, fin)
##### to check what is coming from this for loop #########
    filename = os.path.basename(infile.name)
    print(pat1)
    print(filename)
######################################

with open('R.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvf:

    writer = csv.writer(csvf)
    writer.writerow(header)
    writer.writerow(pat1)
    writer.writerow([filename])
```

Any help would be appreciated , i have read the CSV pages and understand some elements of it , i need a little bit of help thinking about my approach to this. Thank you

Comment: You are assigning to `pat1` in a loop, each time overwriting the value from the previous iteration of the loop.  If you want *all* the `pat1` values, you either need to write them out inside the same loop (in other words, have both the input and output files open at the same time), OR accumulate all of the values in a list (or other such container) so that you can write them all in the second loop.

Comment: Hi Jason, Thanks for your input here. When I `print(pat1)` , i get the values out on screen , so it finds the pattern 4 times in two files - 8 times total. I want to get that same information into the CSV in the format above, so 8 rows with 7 columns if that makes sense. I need to put the output of the pattern search into a CSV loop to update the rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit difficult to test without a suitable `.txt` file, but you need to restructure your script to something like as follows:

```
# use regex on a directory of files and copy into a CSV
import re
import glob
import csv
import os
import io

#Pattern REGEX configuration
patternCPECCC1 = "\/CC(.*?)\/C1"
patternCPET5S6 = "\/T5(.*?)\/S6"
path = "/test/"

#CSV headers
header = ['Column1', 'Column2', 'Column3', 'Column4', 'Column5', 'Column6', 'Column7'] # add more as I expand out the Patterns

with open('R.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvf:
    writer = csv.writer(csvf)
    writer.writerow(header)
    
    # to search DIR defined in path
    for filename in glob.glob(path + "*.TXT"):
        with open(filename) as f_txt:
            data = f_txt.read()
            basename = f_txt.name
        
        pat1 = re.findall(patternCPECCC1, data)

        ##### to check what is coming from this for loop #########
        print(pat1)
        print(basename)
        ######################################

        rows = [next(csv.reader(io.StringIO(row))) + [basename] for row in pat1]
        writer.writerows(rows)
```

1. You need to keep your CSV file open whilst working with all of your `.txt` files.
2. Each element of `pat1` is a single string containing all of the rows. You need to use a `csv.reader()` to split it up into values. This can be done using `io.StringIO` to make the string appear like a file.
3. You need to add your filename to the end of each row.
4. You can then write all rows at the same time using `.writerows()`

Comment: Hi Martin, Thank you for this, I see where this is going, to be honest i wasn't aware of that StringIO , I am going to look further into this to see what it is all about.

It worked anyways and i got `pat1` into the cells from column 1-7, and the pattern i took via REGEX is in each cell.

If i want to add say `pat2` and `pat3` etc beside `pat1` in the CSV , what way would i approach that ?  

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: If i want to add say pat2 and pat3 etc beside pat1 in the CSV , what way would i approach that ?

Comment: It depends if it would be on the same row or on new rows. Also if there would be the same number of rows in `pat2` and `pat3` as in `pat1`.

Comment: Ok so same row, i want to do the same as `pat1` , but put `pat2` in column 8,9,10 etc , then put `pat3` on the same row beside `pat2.`

so each row will have `pat1` `pat2` `pat3` etc. .

same number of rows.

Comment: You probably need to use `zip` to bring multiple items together. I suggest you start a new question. You should add a sample entry from a `.txt` file and show what your desired output would be. I get the feeling a different approach would be better, but would need to see the original data.

Comment: Ok i'll put a question together . see this image here https://ibb.co/BfrK8vx of the desired output , i got this by changing your code to this https://ibb.co/B3XnyfG , but need to shift the row up. `patx` is any regex pattern from a file. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Further question added here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66246383/merge-rows-into-columns-from-for-loop-in-csv