# Merge rows into Columns from FOR Loop in CSV

Tags: python, regex, csv

This Program scans through files ( see sample data below - one file could have 10 data samples in it) in a directory, and extracts data using REGEX (patterns).

The problem i am having is the output is like:

[image: Output to CSV]

```
# use regex on a directory of files and copy into a CSV
import csv
import glob
import io
import re
import os

# Pattern REGEX configuration
patternN1S1 = "\/N1(.*?)\/S1" # reads between /N11,3280,0000,031,037,014,0198,32,1/S1
patternT5S6 = "\/T5(.*?)\/S6" # reads between /T50230,0485,355,389,----,025,08005/S6
#patternNEXT

path = "/test/"

# CSV headers
header = ['Column1', 'Column2', 'Column3', 'Column4', 'Column5', 'Column6',
          'Column7']  # add more as I expand out the Patterns

with open('RR.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvf:
    writer = csv.writer(csvf)
    writer.writerow(header)

    # to search DIR defined in path
    for files in glob.glob(path + "*.TXT"):
        with open(files) as infile:
            infile = open(files)
            filename = os.path.basename(infile.name)
            data = infile.read()

        pat1 = re.findall(patternN1S1, data)
        pat2 = re.findall(patternT5S6, data)

        rows = [next(csv.reader(io.StringIO(row))) for row in pat1]
        rows1 = [next(csv.reader(io.StringIO(row))) + [filename] for row in pat2]
        #rows2 = [next(csv.reader(io.StringIO(row))) + [filename] for row in pat3]

        writer.writerows(rows)
        writer.writerows(rows1)
        #writer.writerows(rows2)
```

What i would like to achieve is for each pattern i make from REGEX, it is extracted from the file(s) and appended to the same row. The program does it successfully with the first row , but the second pattern is added as a row and i would like to keep it in the same row as `pat1` , and any other patterns added.

sample text file

/C111,49634,7001,04,0000,1,0000,06,
1/CE0157,00632,---,---,----,---,C73014/EC000609,48669,14256,35384,00,05,02/EE645000,02173
,19871,00767,00/N11,3280,0000,031,037,014,0198,32,1/S10003,0185,0230,0000,999,0161,34/T10
147,0240,386,392,----,025,0800D/S20018,0238,0240,0161,016,0157,34/T20152,0250,386,389,---
-,025,08005/S30040,0300,0790,0198,043,0153,34/T30175,0300,386,390,----,025,08005/S40067,0
357,1540,0224,060,0150,35/T40197,0370,371,390,----,025,08005/S50096,0418,2320,0269,080,01
48,35/T50230,0485,355,389,----,025,08005/S60109,0446,2620,0294,091,0147,35/T60250,0540,34
7,390,----,025,08005/S70123,0475,2900,0312,101,0148,35/T70272,0620,339,389,----,025,08005
/S80138,0506,3170,0342,109,0152,35/T80297,0695,329,379,----,025,08005/S90151,0523,3390,03
62,114,0155,19/T90315,0785,325,379,----,025,08001/S00162,0542,3580,0373,119,0158,25/T0033
2,0875,325,379,----,025,08001/U10172,0563,3740,0382,123,0162,24/V10350,0950,325,379,----,
025,08001/U20182,0583,3860,0390,128,0165,28/V20370,1025,323,379,----,026,08001/
;

Appreciate any assistance thanks.

Comment: Is the sample text an example of a single row (on one line)? Can there be multiple rows per file?

Comment: Hi Martin, 
It is not a single line there are returns . for example to collect `/EE ..... /N1` ( it goes onto a new line) , I tried `re.findall(patC1CE,data,re.DOTALL)` , it didnt grab it though , will keep looking. Thanks for all your input its looking good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use `zip()` to read the two lists together and then `chain.from_iterable()` to combine each row together:

```
# use regex on a directory of files and copy into a CSV
from itertools import chain
import csv
import glob
import io
import re
import os

# Pattern REGEX configuration
reN1S1 = re.compile("\/N1(.*?)\/S1") # reads between /N11,3280,0000,031,037,014,0198,32,1/S1
reT5S6 = re.compile("\/T5(.*?)\/S6") # reads between /T50230,0485,355,389,----,025,08005/S6
#patternNEXT

path = "/test/"
# CSV headers
header = ['Column1', 'Column2', 'Column3', 'Column4', 'Column5', 'Column6',
          'Column7']  # add more as I expand out the Patterns

with open('RR.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvf:
    writer = csv.writer(csvf)
    writer.writerow(header)

    # to search DIR defined in path
    for file in glob.glob(path + "*.TXT"):
        with open(file) as infile:
            filename = os.path.basename(infile.name)
            data = infile.read()

        rows1 = [next(csv.reader(io.StringIO(row))) for row in reN1S1.findall(data)]
        rows2 = [next(csv.reader(io.StringIO(row))) for row in reT5S6.findall(data)]

        for row in zip(rows1, rows2):
            writer.writerow(list(chain.from_iterable(row)) + [filename])
```

This assumes `rows1` and `rows2` will always have the same number of rows.

Comment: Hi Martin, In the above sample text (which is MULTILINE), I try to capture the data from `/EE...../N1` (second line), according to https://pythex.org/ , `\/EE(.*?)\/N` this should work using re.DOTALL , if i name the variable `patEEN1 = "\/EE(.*?)\/N1"` and use `re.findall(patEEN1,data,re.DOTALL)` I am not getting the data returned. I dont understand why as `re.DOTALL` should pass anything after the `.` .

Comment: As a workaround, you could always use `data = infile.read().replace('\n', '')`

Comment: Thanks Martin , that worked out great , I appreciate the input